# Problema de Conexão Ionic

Tags: ionic, mobile, moodle

Bom dia,

Tenho um projeto em ionic, que há 2 dias não consigo passar da tela inicial, devido a um erro de conexão. Porém, não alterei os arquivos de config, e tenho uma outra versão do mesmo, na play store, que concta normalmente. 
Alguém sabe se poder ser versão, ou como resolver essas situação?

Versão do Ionic: 2.2.3
Versão do Cordova: 6.5.0
Moodle Mobile App.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro apontado da linha:

function consoleLog(type) {
      var console = $window.console || {},
          logFn = console[type] || console.log || noop,
          hasApply = false;

```
  // Note: reading logFn.apply throws an error in IE11 in IE8 document mode.
  // The reason behind this is that console.log has type "object" in IE8...
  try {
    hasApply = !!logFn.apply;
  } catch (e) {}

  if (hasApply) {
    return function() {
      var args = [];
      forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
        args.push(formatError(arg));
      });
      return logFn.apply(console, args);
    };
  }

  // we are IE which either doesn't have window.console => this is noop and we do nothing,
  // or we are IE where console.log doesn't have apply so we log at least first 2 args
  return function(arg1, arg2) {
    logFn(arg1, arg2 == null ? '' : arg2);
  };
}
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Tenta em outro navegador.